# Server-Client in UDP

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp, client-server

My Datagram simple client server program is giving error.Client takes information from server and server also gets information from client.

Here is my Server:

```
package udp;

import java.net.*;

public class DatagramServer implements Runnable {

DatagramPacket pack;
DatagramSocket sock;

DatagramServer() {
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            recieve();
            send();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void send() throws Exception {
    byte data[] = "This is a \n datagram packet".getBytes();
    InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, add, 8000);
    sock = new DatagramSocket();
    sock.send(pack);
    sock.close();
}

public void recieve() throws Exception {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    sock = new DatagramSocket(8000);
    sock.receive(incoming);
    byte[] data = incoming.getData();
    String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DatagramServer();
}
}
```

And here is my Client :

```
package udp;

import java.net.*;

public class DatagramClient {

DatagramPacket pack;
DatagramSocket sock;

DatagramClient() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    receive();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    send();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t2.start();
}

public void receive() throws Exception {
    byte data[] = new byte[1000];
    pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    sock = new DatagramSocket(8000);
    sock.receive(pack);
    System.out.println("Data::" + new String(pack.getData(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("Port::" + pack.getPort());
    sock.close();
}

public void send() throws Exception {

    String s = "KOLI SDF DFEF XFFFSS";
    byte[] b = new byte[1000];
    b = s.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8000);
    sock= new DatagramSocket(8000);
    sock.send(dp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DatagramClient();
}
}
```

I'm getting errors like:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bindBUILD STOPPED  (total time: 4 seconds)
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your server code is trying to bind to the 8000 port each time receive () called. And receive is being called repeatedly from within the while(true) loop. So it tries to bind to the same port again and again.

To fix it remove the UDP socket instantiation i.e

```
sock = new DatagramSocket(8000);
```

From the receive method and put it before your while loop begins.

Comment: how can my Server both receive and send data to Client?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, your server code already does that.

Comment: In your server send method remove this - sock = new DatagramSocket();. Your server should use the same socket to respond as the one it received. On the client side your socket should connect the server's address and port, send data and wait until it received a response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your client and server has some issues such as open same port 8000 in different threads so I have fixed those within the following code.

Client

```
package udp;

import java.net.*;

public class DatagramClient {

    DatagramPacket pack;
    DatagramSocket sock;

    DatagramClient() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        receive();
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
    }

    public void receive() throws Exception {
        byte data[] = new byte[1000];
        pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        sock = new DatagramSocket(8000);
        sock.receive(pack);
        System.out.println("Data::" + new String(pack.getData(), "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Port::" + pack.getPort());
        sock.close();
    }

    public void send() throws Exception {

        String s = "KOLI SDF DFEF XFFFSS";
        byte[] b = new byte[1000];
        b = s.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8000);
        sock= new DatagramSocket(8000);
        sock.send(dp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DatagramClient();
    }
}
```

Server

```
package udp;

import java.net.*;

public class DatagramServer implements Runnable {

    DatagramPacket pack;
    DatagramSocket sock;

    DatagramServer() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                //recieve();
                send();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void send() throws Exception {
        byte data[] = "This is a \n datagram packet".getBytes();
        InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, add, 8000);
        sock = new DatagramSocket();
        sock.send(pack);
        sock.close();
    }

    public void recieve() throws Exception {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        sock = new DatagramSocket(8000);
        sock.receive(incoming);
        byte[] data = incoming.getData();
        String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DatagramServer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example in your answer? i'm totally new here and where i should make change? server or client?

Comment: but server doesn't receive anything

Comment: Check the client console it receives from server. Server only producing udp packets according to given code.

Comment: yeah client receives, but server doesn't..i also need that

Comment: Can you please show me in your solution? thanks in advance